# Shapes not aligned with Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix `X` of size `300 x 100 x 300`. Let's suppose the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.ones((300,100,300))
Y = np.dot(X, X.T)
```

I am getting an error `shapes (300,100,300) and (300,100,300) not aligned: 300 (dim 2) != 100 (dim 1)`

How can I address this error?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

On my phone I was getting an out of memory error when I tried this on a 300, 100, 300 array, so I cut it down to 30, 10, 30. This works but you may have adjust the number of rotation to get the answer you need:

```
>>> X = np.ones((30,10,30))
>>> Y = np.dot(X, np.rot90(X.T,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but are you sure this works as we want?

Comment: @Christina no, I’m not sure since you didn’t provide an expected out put, it does arrange the dimensions of the 2nd input so that you can perform the dot function.